# Where can I learn RCPTT?

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

Where can I learn RCPTT? I need to learn it for a project I am working on. However, there are very limited sources on Internet and the few that are there, are without any examples. Can you recommend me some good book or any site where I can get RCPTT tutorials with examples?

Comment: there documentation site is: https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/getstarted/
|

there api documentation is : http://download.xored.com/q7/docs/ecl-api/latest#

eclipse forum link  is https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/281/

go through the questions in their forum, read the documentation properly. I hope day by day u will improve.